# How to retrieve specific list of data from firebase?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any possible way to get result from child of child. 
I'm looking for multiple answers on a question.!

```
"questions" : {
    "Q1(Random ID )" : {
      "description" : "Deail of Question",
      "idQuestion" : "Q1",
      "time" : "17 Mar 2017 16:18:12",
      "title" : "Title Of Question",
      "user_id" : "bXCeW6jfidbHuMCCCMkDGWcGZRS2"
    },
{
  "Answer" : {
    "81d19e85-8c6c-4824-9fb1-61a7cd316e32" : {
      "dateTime" : "17 Mar 2017 16:22:17",
      "Answer" : "Answer",
      "ProfessorId" : "da587c89-f001-43f2-984d-e6dbac491acc",
      "questionId" : "Q1"
    },
    "e2ec0556-4420-4d2f-b346-0b5cebeb1ebe" : {
      "dateTime" : "17 Mar 2017 16:55:27",
      "Answer" : "Answer 2 on Question 1",
      "answerId" : "0d20d6df-907d-4133-be53-ca6acf6c2ad1",
      "questionId" : "Q1"
    }
  },
```

nodes that have been generated randomly. !
want to do something like this .!

```
mdatabaseReference.child("Answer").child(* Here Im Using "*" Like we used to do in SQl to get all data I knw its not a SQL but its just for conecpt).equalTo(QID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (Answer_List.size() > 0)
                    Answer_List.clear();


                for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
```

Instead of using using `postSnapshot.getKey().equals("QID")`

```
    if(postSnapshot.getKey().equals("QID"))  
 Answertext = postSnapshot.getValue().toString();
```

It will make performance slower I'm looking for some thing faster.!

looking for something like this

```
 mdatabaseReference.child("Answer").child("*").getKey().equals(QID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Firebase Database queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data).

```
mdatabaseReference
  .child("Answer")
  .orderByChild("questionId")
  .equalTo("Q1")
  .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot answerSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(answerSnapshot.child("Answer").getValue());
      }
    }
    ...
```

However, while this will work, I highly recommend that you change your data model to make this type of query more scaleable. Since answers fall under questions, you should model that hierarchy. While you *should not* mix questions and answers, you *should* consider modeling the answers under the question ID:

```
"questions" : {
    "Q1(Random ID )" : {
      "description" : "Deail of Question",
      "idQuestion" : "Q1",
      "time" : "17 Mar 2017 16:18:12",
      "title" : "Title Of Question",
      "user_id" : "bXCeW6jfidbHuMCCCMkDGWcGZRS2"
    },
}
"Answer" : {
  "Q1": {
    "81d19e85-8c6c-4824-9fb1-61a7cd316e32" : {
      "dateTime" : "17 Mar 2017 16:22:17",
      "Answer" : "Answer",
      "ProfessorId" : "da587c89-f001-43f2-984d-e6dbac491acc",
    },
    "e2ec0556-4420-4d2f-b346-0b5cebeb1ebe" : {
      "dateTime" : "17 Mar 2017 16:55:27",
      "Answer" : "Answer 2 on Question 1",
      "answerId" : "0d20d6df-907d-4133-be53-ca6acf6c2ad1",
    }
  }
}
```

With this structure you can get the answers for Q1 with a direct lookup instead of a query (on an every growing list):

```
mdatabaseReference
  .child("Answer")
  .child("Q1")
  .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot answerSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(answerSnapshot.child("Answer").getValue());
      }
    }
    ...
```